# Why does the following code cause an infinite loop ? And how to fix the problem

Tags: javascript, loops

```
let index = 10;
let jump = 2;

for (;;) {
  // Write Your Code Here
     let i = index;
     console.log(i);
     i -= jump;
     if (i === jump) {
         break;
     }
 }
```

I think that I know the logic of the code, but I don't understand why it does loop infinitely

Comment: Why won't the loop break ? I am decrementing the value of the i so that it reaches the value of jump and the loop breaks

Comment: Actually it's `let i = index;` inside the loop making it infinite (it creates a new `i` with value of `10` on every round). Declare and initialize the variable outside of the loop.

Comment: Explanation given below [why the loop is never exited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74596922/20164415). See below.

Comment: I suggest to attach a debugger and execute this code set by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the following code fixes the problem.

```
let index = 10;
let jump = 2;
let i = index;

for (;;) {
  // Write Your Code Here
     
     console.log(i);
     i -= jump;
     if (i === jump) {
         break;
         console.log('broken...')
     }
 }
```

The reason is ***variable i*** is being refreshed with ***static index value 10*** every time it loops. Hence it never breaks.

Comment: Thanks . Now I understood the problem and the solution .

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `10` to `i` for each iteration of the loop so `i` will never be equal
`jump(2)`

**Possible Fix**

```js
let index = 10;
let jump = 2;
let i = index;

for (;;) {
  // Write Your Code Here
     console.log(i);
     i -= jump;
     if (i === jump) {
         break;
     }
 }
```

**OR**

```js
let index = 10;
let jump = 2;

for (;;) {
  // Write Your Code Here
     console.log(i);
     index -= jump;
     if (index === jump) {
         break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
    index = 9 (any odd number);
    jump = 2 (any even number);
    i -= jump; //i will be odd all the time;
```

So "i" will be an odd number;
And "jump" is an even number;

```
    if (i === jump) //odd === even: never match
```

Comment: Good point, but please add also an answer why the loop is infinite with the current values, otherwise this should be only a comment.